# Can you give me a hint for the following?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am a first year uni student learning about linear transformations I encountered the following question if $$T^2=T$$ such that T is from V to V  proof or disproof that T is an Injective function  , what I understood is that  $$T^2$$ is a composition of T on T
secondly I deduced that t can be  the identity function since when applying the transformation twice its the same as applying it once  , it can also be the transformation to 0 such that I am getting zero no matter the input , so I concluded that the sentence is wrong but I am not sure how to deal with this formally , I tried writing something such as  $$T(v1)+T(v2)=T(v1)^2+T(v2)^2$$
$$T(v1)^2-T(v1)+T(v2)^2-T(v2)=0$$
$$ T(T(v1+v2))=T(T(v1))+T(T(v2))$$
I just could not  figure out how to continue

Comment: All you need is one non-injective example to prove that $T$ need not be injective.  As you remark, one of your examples is clearly non-injective (at least, assuming that $V$ has positive dimension).

Comment: but if I can't  think of a counterexample like I did , I would like to have some ability  to use the properties and reach a conclusion

Comment: non positive means 0D?

Comment: Proof by counterexample is a terrific method, when it works.  Here, well...as you have noticed, some $T$ that satisfy the properties are injective and others aren't. So you can't get a general proof that injectivity is impossible.

Comment: As a general rule for these things, try a simple case ($n=1$) first. A linear function in the scalar case is $T(x) = \alpha x$ for some scalar $\alpha$. If the equation is true for all $x$ then $\alpha^2 = \alpha$. Ask yourself if this means that $T$ necessarily injective.

Comment: Yes.  The vector space just containing $0$ is zero dimensional.  And in that case, all maps $V\to V$ are injective.  Obviously, a degenerate case.

Comment: If you want to prove something general, prove that $T^2=T$ implies that $T$ is a projection.  That is, prove that the image of $T$ is a subspace fixed by $T$.  Such a map, like coordinate projection, is clearly not injective in general.

Comment: oh I see this is really helpful,  can I suggest another  case and write my reasoning to get  some intuition?

Comment: Sure.  You can even post it as a solution to your question.  That way people here can comment on it and the site can close the question.

Comment: thanks I did not know about the feature I will try to now  ,

Answer (score 0):

I tried to imagine 2 more scenarios and answer them to get a good intuition on the matter , I may be wrong and I would love nothing more than to be corrected ,

case 1: if $T(x)^2=0$ does $T(x)=0$ have to be zero as well ?,

I went and started with the thinking if there is a case where this is not true could not think of anything, I switched the formate for the case to $$T(T(x))=0 $$
I know that if T(x) is 0 then for certainT(T(x) is zero because  T(0) =0 from the properties of a linear transformation
now I tried to imagine the opposite I where T(x) is not zero and see what happens from there T(num)=num T(num)=0 this case can't always work so I deduced that the T(x) have to be 0
,

case2:
I tried to think of a question similar to the first if $$T(x)^2$$ is injective  does T(x) have to be injective  $$T(v1)^2=T(v1)^2$$ if $$v1=v2$$
$$T(T(v1))=T(T(v2)$$
I see it working for zero  and identity transformation for composition and since it can't be zero according to the condition above it have to be true?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Consider $T=\pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}$

Comment: I.e., $T(x,y)=(y,0)$